# How to set onClick listener on navigation drawer

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Its in **SlidingMenuFragment.java** and I want each item listed clickable. Please help to achieve this.

DRAWER ITEMS

I want this 3 clickable so that I can open a new activity.

```
data.add("One");
data.add("Two");
data.add("Three");
```

[navigation drawer items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3GmV.png)

Thank you for helping.
The code below is from http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-material-design-navigation-drawer-example/

```
package com.manishkpr.androidmaterialnavigationdrawer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.*;

public class SlidingMenuFragment extends Fragment {
List<String>data;
ListView list_view;
SlidingMenuListAdapter adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sliding_menu, null);
    setUpView(root);
    return root;
}
void setUpView(ViewGroup root){
    list_view  =  (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    initList();
    setUpClick();
}
void initList(){
    data = new ArrayList<String>();

    data.add("One");
    data.add("Two");
    data.add("Three");

    adapter = new SlidingMenuListAdapter(getActivity(),data);
    list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
}
void setUpClick(){
    list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                MainActivity.obj.closeDrawer();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hi "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: Please point out your problem in more detail

Comment: I want that Item one, two, and three to be clickable so that I can open new activity.

Comment: The first link is the nav drawer image

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner implementation with more thorough explanations can be found in the android documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

That said, it looks like you already have some clickable list items, all you need to do now is start the new activity within your ItemClickListener. You can make each item do a different thing by referencing the 'position' parameter:

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            MainActivity.obj.closeDrawer();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hi "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Start 'YourActivity' when first item is clicked
            if(position == 0){
                Intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    });
```

I think it is important that you learn some more basic things, such as how to create new Activities and start them before getting too tied up with specific things like Navigation Drawers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                MainActivity.obj.closeDrawer();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hi "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Try to include this to your code
                getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(this, YourAnotherActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

Comment: How can i use switch. Can you provode an example please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As an example you can also try something like this in your code :

```
if(position == 0) {
     Intent AlbumsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, avtivity.class);
     startActivity(AlbumsIntent);
}else if (position==1){
      Intent ArtistsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, avtivity1.class);
      startActivity(ArtistsIntent);
}else if (position==2){
      Intent SongsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity2.class);
      startActivity(SongsIntent);
}else if (position==3){
      Intent CardIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity3.class);
      startActivity(CardIntent);
}else if (position==4){
      Intent LogoutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, avtivity4.class);
      startActivity(LogoutIntent);
}
```